# Starting camera on resume in windows store app

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

We are developing normal bar code scanner app for windows surface tablets. In onNavigatedTo method of page we are invoking camera..

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
        await App.camera.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            VideoDeviceId = devices[1].Id
        });

        cap.Source = App.camera;
        cap.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        await App.camera.StartPreviewAsync();
```

It is working fine.

Now App goes to background and comes back to foreground. But we are unable to invoke camera 
again on resume using same code

```
 await App.camera.StartPreviewAsync();
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use events such as `Activated` and `VisibilityChanged`  :

```
private MediaCapture m_mediaCaptureMgr;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Window.Current.Activated+=Current_Activated;
    Window.Current.VisibilityChanged+=  Current_VisibilityChanged;

}
```

And then `Initialize` and `StartPreview` your camera on **Current_Activated** :

```
private async void Current_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        m_mediaCaptureMgr = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
        await m_mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();
        cap.Source = m_mediaCaptureMgr;
        await m_mediaCaptureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
       new MessageDialog("Unable to start the video capture.").ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

And `Stop` Camera on **Current_VisibilityChanged** :

```
private async void Current_VisibilityChanged(object sender, VisibilityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await m_mediaCaptureMgr.StopPreviewAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    }
}
```